# Display username in the mail sent from smtplib

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I have written a python script to send mail using smtplib.
Everything is working fine except, when the user receives the mail, he isn't able to see my google account name, instead he is getting the mail id. is there a way to make this right?

I guess it's got to do something here but am not sure.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = ','.join(recipients_addr)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
return msg
```

[image]

[image]

The first image is the one sent with smtplib. There is no username.

The second one is sent normally from gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide both the email address and the account name to do this.

The [email.utils.formataddr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.formataddr) function can be used to format the data:

```py
>>> from email import utils
>>> utils.formataddr(('Jane Smith', 'jsmith@example.com'))
'Jane Smith <jsmith@example.com>'
```

In the code the question, you would do something like

```py
from_addr = 'praneeth.vasarla@example.com'
from name = 'Praneeth Vasarla'
msg['from'] = formataddr((from_name, from_addr))
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb I got this error `NameError: name 'formataddr' is not defined`. What package should I install?

Comment: I have used `from email.utils import formataddr` and it worked well. Thanks a lot.